# how to get the storage engine using jdbc

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Is there a way to get the storage engine of a MySql table using JDBC.
I already use metadata to get other table information like columns names, types, primary key , indexes ... but didn't find how o get the engine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Statement stmt = connection.createStatement(); 
stmt = connection.createStatement(); 
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select engine from information_schema.tables where table_name='" + tableName + "';");
rs.next(); 
System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `information_schema` to get the engine type, e.g.:

```
SELECT ENGINE
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA=DATABASE() AND TABLE_NAME='foobar';
```

Comment: thanks used it, and adapted it to my code> didn't used the TABLE_SCHEMA=DATABASE()  as I am connected to my database by a Connection.

Comment: I used this :

    Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
    stmt = connection.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select engine from information_schema.tables where table_name='" + tableName + "';");
    rs.next();
    System.out.println(rs.getString(1));